# To assume an event that never happened did happen

Tags: phrases, academic-writing

While writing a paper on 20th century international relations & the Second World War, I was faced with a situation where I had to 'suppose' Hitler never came to power in Germany, and the Weimar Republic never collapsed.

Would there be an academic term to refer to the assumption of an event that never happened, did in fact happen?

Comment: Over on History.SE they're called "What-if Scenarios" or Hypotheticals.

Comment: Science fiction talks about "alternate world" scenarios.

Comment: It's certainly counterfactual, but you can call it a hypothetical situation if you like, because it's a hypothesis that's being elaborated. If you intend to refer to it more than a couple of times, you should give it a short name for long-term reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One term that conveys this is ***[counterfactual](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/counterfactual)***, defined at the Cambridge Dictionary as "about what did not happen but could have happened". It's used to explore alternative histories, etc.

There are other uses for the word, but it does seem to fit here.